# Java selenium how to reload a webpage after TimeOutException?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, web

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //Timeout after 10 seconds
```

I am using ChromeDriver. This is the code I used to set timeout.

```
try {
    System.out.println("Selenium connected to " + haruhi.link);
    driver.navigate().to(haruhi.link);  //URL to connect
} catch (UnhandledAlertException e) {
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    System.out.println("Timeout, Skip this page");
   skip = true;
} catch (NoSuchWindowException e) {
    skip = true;
}
 if (!skip) {
...
}
```

This is the code that connects to URL.

This code is inside a for loop that iterates the list of String of URLs.
Once "skip" is set true, it does nothing about that webpage and connects to next URL on the next iteration in loop.

What I want to do is when a webpage is hanging (stuck in an infinite load),
I want to catch TimeoutException, skip that webpage and connect to next URL in the loop.

[image]

But once TimeoutException is caught, the code connects to the next URL, but the Chrome does not receive that command.
It prints out

"Selenium connected to http://gall.dcinside.com/board/comment_view/?id=comic_new1&no=5518557&page=1"

But chrome URL still displays

"http://gall.dcinside.com/board/comment_view/?id=comic_new1&no=5518554&page=1"

meaning that driver.get(); did not work.

How do I properly use TimeoutException?

Comment: could you share the for loop code

Comment: How many attempts would you like to retry?

Comment: My browser tab simply stops taking any further commands after TimeoutException. I posted another question with simpler code .. could you please share your thoughts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408374/java-selenium-how-to-properly-refresh-a-webpage-after-timeoutexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the following code,

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Comment: I simplified my code for a better understanding... could you share your knowledge?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408374/java-selenium-how-to-properly-refresh-a-webpage-after-timeoutexception